# I'm trying to write a complex storybook, but I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I'm trying to write a complex storybook, but I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated
'Button' refers to a value, but is being used here as a type. Do you want to use 'typeof Button'? <= Typescript error

```
ToolTip.tsx

import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface Props {
  labelElement: React.ReactNode;
  tooltipElement: React.ReactNode;
}

const Tooltip = ({ labelElement, tooltipElement }: Props) => {
  const [isTooltipVisible, setTooltipVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setTooltipVisible(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setTooltipVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative inline-block">
      <div
        onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
        className="inline-block cursor-pointer"
      >
        {labelElement}
      </div>
      {isTooltipVisible && (
        <div className="z-100 absolute">
          <div
            className={`${labelElement ? 'mt-2' : 'mb-2'} ${
              window.innerHeight - window.pageYOffset < 200
                ? 'bottom-0'
                : 'top-0'
            } border border-gray-300 bg-white px-4 py-2 shadow-2xl`}
          >
            {tooltipElement}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tooltip;
```

```
ToolTip.stories.ts

import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';

import Tooltip from './ToolTip';
import Button from './Button';

const meta = {
  title: 'Tooltip',
  component: Tooltip,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  argTypes: {},
} satisfies Meta<typeof Tooltip>;

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;


//Error
export const TooltipExampleButton: Story = {
  args: {
    labelElement: <Button>button</Button>,
    tooltipElement: 'tooltip',
  },
};

//Good
export const TooltipExampleText: Story = {
  args: {
    labelElement: 'Text',
    tooltipElement: 'tooltip',
  },
};
```

To create the storybook of the Tooltip component above,
I want to use Button component as labelElement but it is deprecated.

My environment is React + Typescript + Tailwind.

storybook version

```
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.12",
    "storybook": "^7.0.18",
    "storybook-addon-react-router-v6": "^1.0.2",
```